# How to improve the perfomance of a MySQL query on Python

Tags: python, mysql

My query is quite simple but it takes too much time to end. I have a database in which there are several tables, I need to check the name and also a variable that contains a datetime information. But for each table i spend more than 100 seconds.

```py
query = "show tables"
cursor.execute(query)
tables_info = cursor.fetchall()

tables_info = [x[0] for x in tables_info]

time_month_year = []

for index in tqdm(range(len(tables_info))):
    monthyearquery = "select tempo from {}".format(tables_info[index])
    cursor.execute(monthyearquery)
    tables_time_info = cursor.fetchall()
    r = tables_time_info[0][0].strftime('%b %Y')
    time_month_year.append(r)
```

Is there any way for me to improve this query? I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: What is tqdm doing?  Just use ‘for table_name in tables_info’

Comment: it shows me a progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the whole table `fetchall()` just to get the first column of the first row `tables_time_info[0][0]`, use `limit 1` in the select to have it returning just a single row.

```
time_month_year = []

for table_name in tables_info:
    query = "select tempo from {} limit 1".format(tables_info)
    cursor.execute(query)
    tables_time_info = cursor.fetchall()
    r = tables_time_info[0][0].strftime('%b %Y')
    time_month_year.append(r)
```

Note that you can also use fetchone but it won't bring a performance boost since you've only fetched 1 row anyway, its just more elegant

```
tables_time_info = cursor.fetchone()
r = tables_time_info[0].strftime('%b %Y')
```

Comment: thanks! It solved my problem. What does fetchall actually do?

Comment: `.fetchall()` will execute the full select in MySQL and load the entire result in memory in python.

Comment: Now it returns me 'nonetype' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You observe that with fetchone?